# Running bisect via os.system gives weird error "No testable commit found." while running from bash is ok

Tags: python, git, git-bisect

I'm running bisect like this (tried replacing with `subprocess`, for good measure. Same results...):

```
os.chdir(repo_head)
os.system('git bisect start')
os.system('git bisect bad  XXX')
os.system('git bisect good YYY')
```

and getting

```
No testable commit found.
Maybe you started with bad path parameters?
1024
```

on the last command. If I swap the good and bad, I get the error on the last command again. If I ignore, I can run my tests, but nect time I'll enter a good/bad command, I get this error again...

Running directly from bash does not give any errors:

```
:~/Work (develop)$ git bisect start
Already on 'develop'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/develop'.
:~/Work (develop)$ git bisect good 9b7c546
:~/Work (develop)$ git bisect bad 63311c8
Bisecting: 1 revision left to test after this (roughly 1 step)
[7b7e58f8d13d48e937b84fc7898aa0fadd5fdead] Merged in ZZZ
```

Python 3.5.2, git 2.7.4

---

UPDATE:

Changing my bisect start to bisect start *BAD* *GOOD* seems to work fine but I don't get why

Comment: I am confused by your update: you say changing X to X (which leaves it unchanged) makes it work.

Comment: Lol... I wrote ... To bisect start <bad> <good> without realizing the <> are left unseen... Changed it to * instead and now the sentence makes sense

Comment: OK, that at least is less puzzling. I don't know what's causing the problem at this point, though. bisect is stateful and each command moves the machinery through various states, so `git bisect start <bad> <good>` is more efficient as it doesn't waste intermediate effort, but they should behave the same as `start` re-sets state similar to the way `git bisect reset` re-sets state afterward.